# Question about outdated "amplidyne" technology

Tags: voltage, current, electric-machine

Can someone please help me understand something better about "amplidyne" technology that was used back in the day.

**What I know**

It appears to be a dc motor generator that acts like an amplifier which then allows excitation to be varied by small amount (input power) to produce large output power.

Referencing the conditions and picture provided.

R = 1 ohm

Terminal v = 100 v

Amps = 100 amps

Input power = 100 watts

Output power = 1000 watts

[image]

What does the following statement mean: **It will be found that when R is zero, the field current required to circulate 100 amperes through the short circuited armature winding is only about 5% of the field current required when terminal E is 100 volts.**

Does this simply mean that field current to produce 100 V will be less with shorted brushes compared when  the brushes not short-circuited?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Amplidyne is a strange beast, it can do various things based on the setup. Something like old  days operational amplifier. It has four brushes, not just two.

Comment: It might be saying that it takes 100A of field current to get 100V across R=1Ω.  But when R≈0Ω it only takes 5% of 100A, or 5A, to get the same current flowing through the R?

Comment: There's not enough context there.  What's "terminal E", for starters.  Post a link, or more text.

Comment: Careful, if input power is 100W and output is 1kW, then >900W mechanical energy (including losses) must be put in.